# module squarify on Juypter notebook error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, squarify

I'm trying to create a treemap chart on juypter notebooks but somehow it isn't able to find the module.

I've already installed it in bash with 'pip install squarify' as well as using python by 'import squarify' there isn't any issues but when I try to import in juypter notebooks it says as seen in the picture!

[image of juypter notebook that says squarify module is not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTfCA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometimes when there is more than one copy of Python installed on your computer. This [blog](http://takluyver.github.io/posts/i-cant-import-it.html) is very helpful.